# Когда конкретно и в каком файле запускать сессию в yii?

Tags: php, yii2, сессия

Настраиваю мультиязычность на Yii2 Basic. Хочу в сессии хранить язык интерфейса, выбранный пользователем. Нужно перед запуском всех контроллеров обновить язык интерейса в `config['language']` значением из сессии.

В каком файле / контроллере / месте приложения мне обратиться к сессии, вынуть значение и прописать его в конфиг так, чтобы все компоненты приложения, включая attributeLabels в моделях, при обращении к config читали уже обновленное значение языка?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Появилась идея использовать голый PHP прямо в точке входа index.php и пошарить в сессии до запуска самого приложения (код ниже). Не знаю, насколько правильно так делать с архитектурной и проектной точки зрения. Всё ещё нужен совет!

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

// Вот тут стучимся в сессию
$config = require __DIR__ . '/../config/web.php';
session_start();
$config['language'] = isset($_SESSION['language']) ? $_SESSION['language'] : 'ru-RU';

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо создать компонент, который добавить в автозагрузку (чтобы он отрабатывал в момент инициализации приложения). В компоненте установить необходимую локализацию. Что-то типа такого:

```
public function init(){
    parent::init();
    $lang = Yii::$app->session->get('lang', 'en-EN');
    Yii::$app->language = $lang;
}
```

В конфиге в секцию bootstrap
`'bootstrap' => ['log', 'ComponentName'],`

Comment: Два уточнения. 1) Поставить компонент в автозагрузку - это значит прописать его в config['components']? 2) В компоненте - это значит в конструкторе компонента? Просто не представляю, как обратиться к компоненту из кода до обращения к какому-либо контроллеру...

Comment: Дополнил ответ. К компоненту нет необходимости обращаться. Он будет загружен в начале инициализации приложения и с помощью метода init() изменит настройки конфигурации приложения.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо за ответ :-)